# Gradle + Git - enforcing a version change upon merge to master

Tags: git, versioning, semantic-versioning, gradle

I am leading a team of developers creating a Java library.  We are following the standard [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) model.  The code is versioned with Git.  Artifacts are built and pushed to an artifact server using Gradle.

As is the standard, the artifact version, when published, is determined in `build.gradle` with the line `version 'xxx.xxx.xxx'`.  I want to enforce a policy that all merges to the **master** branch require that this `version` be changed.  This is to ensure we don't accidentally publish a new artifact over an old version, which could cause a dependency nightmare for downstream users of our library.

It looks to me like the Git [Client Side Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) may hold the answer, but the methodology for scanning through the changes in a merge and looking for a particular one eludes me.

Note that I do not need the hook to do any intelligence around the changes to the `version` line.  I trust the developers increment the values correctly.  This is just about making sure a forgetful dev (which will undoubtedly be me) is reminded that the `version` needs to be changed.

Comment: Should each commit on master represent a release? What happens if there is a problem and you want to revert the master branch to an earlier version, how could you do that? Wouldn't it be better to put a quality gate before the actual release process to ensure that you are releasing a new version? An alternative is incrementing the release number directly *after* each release, but that doesn't play well with semver.